# VirtualBox Guest VM (win7) cant ping Host PC (win10) - Bridged connection

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, ping, bridged

My virtualbox Win7 VM can ping the rest of the devices on my home network however the only machine it cannot is the HOST pc. I have tried to ping the VM from various other machines and all of them seem to have pinged the VM successfully.

The firewall on the VM is obviously not making any difference but just in case I left it OFF. The HOST pc's firewall was also turned OFF. I am using the Bridged connection setup for the VM. The Host is running a win10 os.

I have shared a folder on the VM just to check if it could be discovered on the LAN network. It did got discovered. All devices can "see" it and actually access it. The host can access it too. And yet the ping guest-to-host doesn't go through! Very strange.

My initial objective when I decided to spin up this VM was to make that VM accessible over the network for remote desktoping. While this is still my primary objective, I have stumbled upon the issue that I have described in the thread above.

I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue.

Comment: "Bridged" means exactly that, it doesn't have its own IP so it cannot ping the host. You need NAT for that.

Comment: Adapter one is left as is - Bridged. Adapter two is now enabled and set to NAT. The result is the same as before - guest-to-host no ping. 
Any other suggestions ?

Comment: What other suggestions are you expecting? Things are how they are and we can't know your specific setup and why you have 2 adapters.

Comment: The VM has to act  as if it is on the home network. Needs to be discoverable by any device, be able to share files, to access other devices' shared files... This is basicaly what is the near term target.
As far as the setup goes I have a home wifi router with DHCP enabled. My Host's ip is reserved 192.168.0.4 . The VM is spun on that host using virtual box hypervisor, Default networking settings are kept. I have switched to NAT network adapter setting as @ChanganAuto suggested earler and disabled  any other adapter.

Comment: The machines are just that - separate machines.  Just like having physical machines on a LAN. Make sure Network Discovery is ON, File and Print Sharing is ON and like settings. I use Default Firewall and it does not get in the way. I share files between VMs, Host and VMs and VMware VMs with Hyper-V VMs.

Comment: Also, Bridged connections should be on an LAN subnet, and life is longer and easier with one subnet. NAT uses the VM app internal network but you can cross over to the LAN with IP addressing.

Comment: @John I wonder if it is my wifi NIC model that is causing the issue. I suspect that based on several reports over the internet that vbox doesnt cope well with physical wifi NIC being in bridge mode with a VM's virtual adapter. I am unaware of your setup but curious to know more how did you achieve it. I got bridge mode to work by setting the same MAC to the virtual and the physical adapters. This in turn made the VM's IP being the same too as the router's DHCP doesnt distinguish  HOST from VM. 
The bridge mode doesnt perform as I expected so I am still thinking how to make it work properly.

Comment: Try a USB Wireless NIC and see if that works.

Comment: I am going to look for such. Meanwhile I was thinking maybe there is a way to mimic the bridge functionality by utilising the rest of the available connection modes. Could such setup be pulled up?